# Array of registers in asm

Tags: c, gcc, x86, sse, inline-assembly

How would you define a pointer to a XMM register in asm()?
Like accessing array elements in a loop how can you access registers in asm using a counter?
I tried to do it in the following code:

```
float *f=(float*)_aligned_malloc(64,16);
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    asm volatile
        (
        "movaps (%1),%%xmm%0"
        :
        :"r"(i),"r"(f+4*i)
        :"%xmm%0"
        );
```

But the compiler gives me this error:

```
unknown register name '%xmm%0' in 'asm'
```

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a horrible idea compared to using assembler macros or actually manual unrolling.  Your code would totally break if gcc decided not to fully unroll the loop, because it can only work with compile-time constant indexing.

Also, there's no way to tell the compiler which register you're putting the result in, so **this is basically useless**.  I'm only answering as a silly exercise in using GNU C inline-asm syntax, not because this answer is possibly useful in any project.

---

That said, you can do it using an `"i"` constraint and [a `c` operand modifier](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86Operandmodifiers) to format the immediate as a bare number, like `1` instead of `$1`.

```
void *_aligned_malloc(int, int);
void foo()
{
    float *f=(float*)_aligned_malloc(64,16);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        asm volatile (
        "movaps %[input],%%xmm%c[regnum]"
        :
        // only compiles with optimization enabled.
        :[regnum] "i"(i), [input] "m"(f[4*i])
        :"%xmm0", "%xmm1", "%xmm2", "%xmm3"
        );
    }
}
```

gcc and clang, with `-O3`, are able to fully unroll and make `i` for each iteration a compile-time constant that can match an `"i"` constraint.  [This compiles on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'void+*_aligned_malloc(int,+int)%3B%0Avoid+foo()%0A%7B%0A++++float+*f%3D(float*)_aligned_malloc(64,16)%3B%0A++++for(int+i%3D0%3Bi%3C4%3Bi%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++asm+volatile+(%0A++++++++%22movaps+%25%5Binput%5D,%25%25xmm%25c%5Bregnum%5D%22%0A++++++++:%0A++++++++:%5Bregnum%5D+%22i%22(i),+%5Binput%5D+%22m%22(f%5B4*i%5D)%0A++++++++:%22%25xmm0%22,+%22%25xmm1%22,+%22%25xmm2%22,+%22%25xmm3%22%0A++++++++)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:36.31156930126002,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dskylake',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang500,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dskylake',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+5.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:57.472412933632434,n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:icc18,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dskylake',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+icc+18+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%234)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:100,l:'4',m:23.352680051557005,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:4,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%234+with+x86-64+icc+18',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:19.174907014810568,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:63.68843069873997,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

```
# gcc7.3 -O3
foo():
    subq    $8, %rsp
    movl    $16, %esi
    movl    $64, %edi
    call    _aligned_malloc(int, int)       # from a dummy prototype so it compiles
    movaps (%rax),%xmm0
    movaps 16(%rax),%xmm1          # compiler can use addressing modes because I switched to an "m" constraint
    movaps 32(%rax),%xmm2
    movaps 48(%rax),%xmm3
    vzeroupper                     # XMM clobbers also include YMM, and I guess gcc assumes you might have dirtied the upper lanes.
    addq    $8, %rsp
    ret
```

Note that I've only told the compiler about reading the first `float` of every group of 4.

---

ICC `-O3` says `catastrophic error: Cannot match asm operand constraint` even with `-O3`.  With optimization disabled, gcc and clang have the same problem, of course.  For example, gcc -O0 will say:

```
<source>: In function 'void foo()':
<source>:11:10: warning: asm operand 0 probably doesn't match constraints
         );
          ^
<source>:11:10: error: impossible constraint in 'asm'
Compiler returned: 1
```

Because without optimization, `i` isn't a compile-time constant and can't match an `"i"` (immediate) constraint.

---

**Obviously you can't use an `"r"` constraint**; that would fill in the asm template with something like `%xmm%eax` if the compiler picked `eax`.

---

Anyway, this is useless because you can't use destination register.  All you can do is tell the compiler that all of the possible destination registers are clobbered.  It's not safe to write to a clobbered register in one asm statement and then assume the value is still there in a later asm statement.

**x86, like all other architectures, can't index the architectural registers using a runtime value.  Register numbers *must* be hard-coded into the instruction stream.**

(Some microcontrollers, like AVR, have memory-mapped registers, so you can index them by indexing the memory that aliases the register file.  But this is rare, and x86 doesn't do it.  It would interfere with out-of-order execution in a similar way to self-modifying code.  And BTW, SMC (or branching to one of 16 different versions of an instruction) is the only option for runtime indexing of the register file.)

Comment: Really an interesting answer. But gcc's behavior looks strange, whether a value is constant shouldn't depend on optimization, I would expect it reject the code all the time.

Comment: @liliscent: This treatment of constants is useful for cases like an inline helper function that uses intrinsics like `_mm_srli_si128` (`psrldq` byte shift) where the shift count has to be a compile-time constant (because the instruction is only available with an immediate count; there's no register form).  In C++ you could use a template parameter, but C doesn't have that, and allowing a function like `foo(int count)` to compile when the caller passes constant is useful.  (As long as you declare it `static inline`, because the compiler can't make a stand-alone definition.)

Comment: @liliscent: Also keep in mind that an `"i"` constraint is often used in cases like `"ri" (input)` to allow the compiler to provide the input in a register, or as an immediate constant if (after optimization) it is. 
 e.g. for an instruction like `add %1, %0`, x86 allows `add %edx, %eax` or `add $123, %eax`.  (It also allows memory source operands, so a `"rmi"` input constraint works.)  It's also possible for code to not compile if the compiler runs out of registers, e.g. if you had a bunch of `"ri"` constraints and not enough of them are immediates...

Comment: **Inline asm is a dance between you and the optimizer**, designed to make it possible to use an instruction while gimping optimization as little as possible.  (But it still defeats constant propagation of course, so don't do it unless you can't get the asm you want any other way.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm.)
 Writing code that requires optimization to compile is often a bad idea, but it's impossible to use different instructions depending on which option the constraint used, so (especially for non-x86) doing so may be the only way to get optimal asm.

Comment: Oh okay. Very helpful information right there. At least now I know how "i" constrait and -O3 work. Thanks Peter. You're da man.

Comment: Another possibility for runtime indexing of registers is to write each register to an array in memory and then do an indexed read into the array. This is probably usually worse than the indirect jump to a `mov` for 16 registers but it might be better if the range of registers is restricted. You could also hybridize the jump and write-off based approaches, perhaps to improve prediction behavior.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Oh right.  Store / index is basically how gcc implements variadic functions with register args.

Answer (score 2):

You can't -- there is no way to index into the register file.

If you want to use multiple registers in sequence, you will need to unroll the loop and name each of the registers explicitly.

Comment: Are you sure? Each register is associated with an opcode. Can't we use that opcode as index to access registers?

Comment: This is the right answer, but see my answer for silly compiler tricks that would let this compile in a useless way.  I don't see any way to extend this to *useful* loop unrolling by the compiler.

Comment: @Tuhnri The opcodes have to be present in your program when it is compiled. They can't be the result of a computation performed by your program. (Outside of self-modifying code and other dirty tricks.)